# Cannot install openjdk-7-jdk on Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, java

I'm currently using ubuntu 14 as my OS. I want to install openjdk-7-jdk on Ubuntu but I have an error when I typed `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. Here is the error message :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
  openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get -f install openjdk-7-jdk` but did not work.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have some broken packages so before installing openjdk . run command

> sudo apt-get -f install

it will install all broken dependency then run command

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

it will work

Comment: Works, Brillant !